# Changing the arrows into $\mapsto.$

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

I wanna change the arrows into $\mapsto$ in the following diagram:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=<-]
  & s'_1 \ar[rd,"j_1^*"]\\
  s \ar[ru,"i_1^*"] \ar{r}{i_2^*} \ar[rd,"i_3^*"'] & s'_2 \ar[r,"j_2^*"] & s'\\
  & s'_3 \ar[ru,"j_3^*"']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes is helpful to check package documentation ;-). Arrows are described in section *1.3 Changing arrow tips*, page 3 ( {tikzcd} Commutative diagrams with Ti*k*Z;  manual, version 0.9f)

Comment: Do you have a link for that document please? @Zarko

Comment: It is part of package bundle, but you can find it on CTAN. It can bi find by help of uncle google: search for "tikz-cd.sty".

Comment: hahaha  uncle google @Zarko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={<-|}]
  & s'_1 \arrow[rd,"j_1^*"]\\
  s \ar[ru,"i_1^*"] \ar{r}{i_2^*} \ar[rd,"i_3^*"'] & s'_2 \ar[r,"j_2^*"] & s'\\
  & s'_3 \ar[ru,"j_3^*"']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the vertical bar is somewhat larger than with the `mapsto` key, which is made to replicate a normal `\mapsto` arrow.

Comment: That's right, but the arrows themselves are very large, so I don't think this is a real problem. Of course, with   `pstricks`, you would have full control on the arrow the vertical bar size.

Comment: With Ti*k*Z you have, according to my understanding, even more control, cf. the `arrows.meta` library. Anyway, this was just to say that the `mapsto`, `mapsfrom` etc. keys can be used to reproduce an arrow that resembles `\mapsto` more closely.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=mapsfrom]
  & s'_1 \ar[rd,"j_1^*"]\\
  s \ar[ru,"i_1^*"] \ar{r}{i_2^*} \ar[rd,"i_3^*"'] & s'_2 \ar[r,"j_2^*"] & s'\\
  & s'_3 \ar[ru,"j_3^*"']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```